# Error: Cannot set headers after they are sent back to the client in express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http-proxy-middleware

I am having issues while doing some complex stuff inside middleware. I know i should be getting this done in a route or some small function but I had no choice.

This is the entire middleware:

```js
app.use(async function addReqUser(req,res,next) {
    if (req.cookies) {
        let token = req.cookies['session-token'];
        let user = {};
    async function verify() {
    //google auth function
        const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
            idToken: token,
            audience: CLIENT_ID, 
        });

        const payload = ticket.getPayload();
        user.name = payload.name;
        user.email = payload.email;
        user.picture = payload.picture;
      }
      verify()
      .then(async ()=>{
          req.user = user;

          const user = await User.find({ email: req.user.email }).select("_id").exec();
          req.user.id = user[0]._id

          res.locals.user = req.user //populate the user with an id

          next();
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
         return res.redirect('/')
      })
    }
    next()
})
```

`The error just says [ERR HTTP_HEADERS_SENT] Cannot set headers after they are sent back to the client`

Help me with this.

Your fast response in appreciated.

Comment: could you provide middleware code ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi this is the entire middleware what else do you want. The error is in this code piece

Comment: Maybe the error is because of asynchronous hell? I used three of them and also many requests, response. Can it be shortened, simplified and improved?

Answer (score 0):

If `req.cookies` is set and the `verify()` call is successful, `next()` will be executed *twice*: once after the asynchronous invocation of `verify()` and once more at the end of the `.then` function.

On the other hand, if `verify()` fails, the `res.redirect` call in the `.catch` function sets a header *after* the first execution of `next()`.

Both can lead to the observed error. A middleware should either

- optionally set headers and then call `next()` (once!) or
- optionally set headers and then send a response (e.g., via `res.send`), but not call `next()`.

Comment: Thanks this helped me to catch up the problem @Heiko TheiBen

Answer (score 0):

You have not used async and await for verify function, you can modify you app.use to the following code

```
app.use(async function addReqUser(req, res, next) {
    if (req.cookies) {
        let token = req.cookies['session-token'];
        let user;
        async function verify() {
            //google auth function
            return client.verifyIdToken({
                idToken: token,
                audience: CLIENT_ID,
            });

        }
        const response = await verify()
        const payload = response.getPayload()

        if (payload.email) {
            user.name = payload.name;
            user.email = payload.email;
            user.picture = payload.picture;
         
            const userDoc = await User.find({ email: req.user.email }).select("_id").exec();
         
            req.user = userDoc;
            req.user.id = userDoc[0]._id;
            res.locals.user = req.user //populate the user with an id
            return next()

        } else {
            return res.redirect('/')
        }
    }
    next()
})
```

While using the .then on verify, the code is not waiting for verify() Promise  to complete & next() after the if block is executed first

Comment: this code is somehow blocking and the browser just keeps on loading

Comment: You'll need to remove the else part and check if the payload contains error & then redirect to '/' else return next @Saswat

Answer (score 0):

The req.cookies was being called and the next() was being executed twice. After some suggestions and coding here's the solution:

```js
app.use(function addReqUser(req, res, next) {
    
    if (Object.hasOwnProperty.bind(req.cookies)('session-token')) { //has a session-token
        let user = {};
        async function verify() {
            let token = req.cookies['session-token'];
            //google auth function
            const ticket = await client.verifyIdToken({
                idToken: token,
                audience: CLIENT_ID,
            });
            const payload = ticket.getPayload()

            if (payload) {
            user.name = payload.name;
            user.email = payload.email;
            user.picture = payload.picture;
            
            req.user = user;

            const userDoc = await User.find({ email: req.user.email }).select("_id").exec();
       
            req.user.id = userDoc[0]._id;
            res.locals.user = req.user //populate the user with an id

        } 

        }
        verify()
        .then(()=>{
          next();
      })
      .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err)
          res.redirect('/')
      })
    } else {
        next();
    }
})
```